# How to diagnose a slow network on Fedora 28?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, backup, broadcom

Experiencing very slow network throughput on my linux Fedora 28 box.

Barely getting over 4 MB/s down (~39 Mbps) using `speedtest-cli`, I can sometimes get near 8 MB/s down using wget to download test file.

The more serious problem is this issue seems to effect local intranet was well.

Transferring files from windows to linux Samba share (NVMe, xfs) via copy/paste through windows explorer (network share) results in the same or worse speeds.

I've also tried just copying a single zip file, same results.

I can transfer files very fast locally on the linux machine (between NVMe, SSD, HDD, with differing schemes including ext4, xfs, ntfs).

When downloading from outside my network to my windows PC, I get ~30 MB/s (~250 Mbps) down. So I know both cable and modem/router can handle throughput.

So if not modem/router, and not disks, this seems to me all that remains is network / interface on the linux machine.... from `lspci -v` I see the ethernet controllers are using kernel driver `tg3`

However, I'm uncertain as to where to start in troubleshooting / remedying this...

I've also found this post which seems like similar situation (not include VPN nonsense).
As mentioned, I tried updating my `/etc/resolv.conf` to use public DNS (1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, etc), but same result.

**Environmental Information**

```
➜  ~ sudo uname -rvmpios
Linux 4.18.7-200.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 10 15:44:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  ~ sudo smbstatus -V
Version 4.8.5
```

ISP: Comcast Xfinity (250 Mbps DOWN / 10 Mbps UP)

Modem/Router: Netgear C7000-100NAS (fw V1.01.32) (Modem variant of Nighthawk AC1900)

Linux PC: Fedora 28, i7 4770k on ASRock z77 Pro, Broadcom NetLink BCM57781 (lspci -v reports Kernel driver `tg3`)

Windows Test PC: Win 10, i7 8700k on ASRock z370 Pro, Aquantia AQtion 10Gbit Network Adapter (driver v1.42.33.0)

Here is the `speedtest-cli` result from linux PC:

```
➜  ~ speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Comcast Cable (255.255.255.0)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by CenturyLink, Inc (Seattle, WA) [XXXXX km]: XXXXXX ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 69.89 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: 11.85 Mbit/s
```